# Analytical Solution of a Laplace Equation with Given Boundary and Initial Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I'm trying to solve the following Laplace equation analytically:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} &= 0
\end{align*}
Subject to the boundary conditions:
\begin{align*}
u(0, y) &= 0 \\
u(\pi, y) &= 0
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
u(x, 0) &= \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
u_y(x, 0) &= 0
\end{align*}

I tried to find the analytical solution as follows

1. **Assume a Solution Form**: Start by assuming that the solution can be written as
   \begin{align*}
   u(x, y) = X(x)Y(y) .
   \end{align*}
2. **Substitute into Equation**:
   \begin{align*}
    X''(x)Y(y) + X(x)Y''(y) = 0 
   \end{align*}
3. **Separate Variables**: Divide the equation by $X(x)Y(y)$ to separate the variables:
   \begin{align*}
    \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = -\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}
   \end{align*}
   This implies that each side must be equal to a constant, which we can call $-\lambda$, because $x$  and $y$ are independent.
4. **Form Two Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs)**: We now have two separate ODEs:

\begin{align*}
  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;X''(x) + \lambda X(x) = 0 \\
  Y''(y) - \lambda Y(y) = 0 
\end{align*}

5. **Solving the Ode's and combining the different solutions**:
   \begin{align*}
     u(x,y) = \frac{\pi}{8} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{n}{4n^2 - 1} \sin(nx)\cosh(ny)
   \end{align*}
   The problem here is that the final solution diverges due to the **exponential** nature of the $\cosh$ function.
   **What have I done wrong in the solution?**

Thank you!

Comment: Your boundary conditions at $y=0$ are appropriate for a hyperbolic system, not for this, an elliptic one.

Comment: Your boundary conditions are inconsistent as $u(\pi,0)$ must simultaneously be $0$ and $1$

Comment: @Aruralreader Thank you,
Could you suggest resources for identifying appropriate boundary conditions for each type?

Comment: @NinadMunshi
Thank you

Comment: For an elliptic system like yours typical boundary conditions would be $u = f$ (Dirichlet) or $\partial u/\partial n = g$ (Neumann) or $u + \alpha\partial u/\partial n = h$ (Robin) on various portions of the boundary, or perhaps $\vert u(x)\vert$ remaining bounded as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If $u$ is defined over then entire space, then it *must* diverge as a consequence of Liouville's theorem, which states that the only bounded harmonic functions over all of Euclidean space are constant.